# I want to use ForeignKey Serializer

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

```
I have these Models Below


class Campaign(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/")
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, related_name="products")
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    market_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    selling_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to show campaign_wise products. But i cant find any solution for this. Though i tried reading the docs of DRF

Here is my Serializer

```
class CampaignProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ['title', 'products']

Whenever i try to run this i get 'Product' object has no attribute 'products'
```

Here is my URL

```
path('campaign_products/<int:id>/', CampaignProducts.as_view()),
```

Here is my View:

```
class CampaignProducts(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        campaigns = Campaign.objects.all()
        query = Product.objects.filter(campaign_id = id)
        serializer = CampaignProductsSerializer(query, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you should make two serializers, one for the `Product` and one for the `Campaign`, so:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title']  # etc.


class CampaignProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ['title', 'products']
```

In the view, you then serializer a `Campaign`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# returns the title of the campaign, and the products
class CampaignProducts(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        campaign = get_object_or_404(Campaign, id=id)
        serializer = CampaignProductsSerializer(campaign)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In case you do not want to include the data of the campaign, we can work with the `ProductSerializer`:

```
# returns only the related products
class CampaignProducts(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, id):
        products = Product.objects.filter(campaign_id=id)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response({'data': serializer.data})
```